# how to subset from a data frame using sqldf

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I want to subset only the cards that are :jack,queen,king using sqldf

```
color <- rep(c("black","red"),each=26)
suit <- rep(c("clubs","spades","diamonds","hearts"),each=13)
name <- rep(c("ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","jack","queen","king"),4)
rank <- rep(c(1:13),4)
value <- rep(c(1:9,rep(10,4)),4)
deck52 <- data.frame(color,suit,name,rank,value)
F <- filter(deck52,name=="jack" | name=="queen" | name=="king")
```

this what I have tried:

```
> F <- sqldf("select*from deck52 where name= 'jack'and 'queen' and 'king'")
> F
[1] COLOR SUIT  NAME  RANK  VALUE
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> F <- sqldf("select*from deck52 where name= 'jack', 'queen',  'king'")
Error: near ",": syntax error
> F <- sqldf("select*from deck52 where name= 'jack'& 'queen' & 'king'")
> F
[1] COLOR SUIT  NAME  RANK  VALUE
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) 
F <- sqldf("select*from deck52 where name= 'jack'|'queen'|'king'")
[1] COLOR SUIT  NAME  RANK  VALUE
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Maybe try `sqldf("select * from deck52 where name = 'jack' OR name = 'queen' OR name = 'king'")` or `sqldf("select * from deck52 where name IN ('jack', 'queen', 'king')")`?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

- the first attempt uses `and` where `or` is needed.  `name` cannot be 'jack' and 'queen' and 'king' at the same time. It can only be one of them or none so we need `or`.
- the other attempts have syntax errors
- do not use `F` as a variable name since it also means `FALSE` and can cause a confusion
- always include `library` statements for all code posted in the question so that the code is complete.

Use one of these:

```
library(sqldf)

FF2 <- sqldf("select * 
  from deck52 
  where name = 'jack' or name = 'queen' or name = 'king'")

FF3 <- sqldf("select * 
  from deck52 
  where name in ('jack', 'queen', 'king')")

# name has more than 3 characters in it
FF4 <- sqldf("select * 
  from deck52 
  where length(name) > 3 ")

royals <- data.frame(name = c("jack", "queen", "king"))
FF5 <- sqldf("select * 
  from deck52 
  join royals using (name)")

FF6 <- sqldf("select * 
  from deck52 
  where name >= 'jack'")
```